# Passing and accessing parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an `Object` called `Person` which has the following attributes; `id`,`name`,`school`.

In another class called `Occupation`, i have a method called `addOccupation`.

1.) I need to pass a parameter of `Person` to this. How should i write the method signature for this ?

2.) How do i pass the parameter from another class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Person

```
Occupation *occu= [[Occupation alloc]init];
[occu addOccupation:parameter];
[occu release];
```

in Occupation.h

```
-(void)addOccupation:(NSString *)parameter;
```

int occupation.m

```
-(void)addOccupation:(NSString *)parameter
{
    NSLog(@"parameter");
}
```

Comment: This is how to pass values to the Method,h so now how can i write the method signature ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but 1 more question. Does the method signature be `-(void)addOccupation:(Occupation *)parameter;` ? Can i write it this way ?

Comment: @Trisha, I too have a doubt! What happened to your acting career!?!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an object called Person or a class named Person?
I am very unclear why you have a class named Occupation that you want to pass in a Person to, since that would seem more of attribute of a person.  The basic idea is that Occupation class would have the following method:

```
- (void) addOccupationWithPerson: (Person*) person;
```

Now that you have it written out, it makes no sense.  What I assume you want is to add an occupation to a person and the @interface level attribute signature would be:

```
@property (retain) Occupation* occupation;
```

and the @synthesize in the .m file.

Then somewhere you would have:

```
Occupation* currentOccupation = ...
Person* currentPerson = ...

currentPerson.occupation = currentOccupation;
```

I hope that helps a little.